# Vertical panning gesture

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I have just upgraded to hammer.js version 2, and I need to change the way that I am handling events where the user pans vertically. I was reading the docs, and it says that only horizontal panning is supported. Why is this the case, and is there an alternative for handling vertical panning events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical panning is supported! The getting started page explains this.

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(element);
mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL });

mc.on("pan", function(ev) {
   console.log(ev);
});
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'element.addEventListener(type, handler, false)')` with this code: `var mc = new Hammer.Manager($('body'));`

Comment: I'm guessing that Hammer is expecting a DOM element, not a jQuery object.